# Requests to controllers with umlauts (special characters) doesn't work with body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Given the following controller (created with Visual Studio 15.8.2 → WebApi template):

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class StädteController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly List<string> Städte = new List<string>{"Berlin","Hamburg","München","Köln","Frankfurt","Stuttgart","Düsseldorf","Dortmund","Essen"};

    // GET api/Städte
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return Städte;
    }

    // Post api/Städte/Leipzig
    [HttpPost("{id}")]
    public void Post(string id)
    {
        if (!Städte.Contains(id))
            Städte.Add(id);
    }

    // Post api/Städte
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] IEnumerable<string> städte)
    {
        Städte.AddRange(städte?.Except(Städte) ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>());
    }
}
```

Any request without payload will work (OK 200 is returned):

- `GET https://localhost:44301/api/Städte`
- `GET https://localhost:44301/api/St%C3%A4dte`
- `POST https://localhost:44301/api/Städte/Leipzig`
- `POST https://localhost:44301/api/St%C3%A4dte/Leipzig`

Requests with a body **don't work** (NOT FOUND 404 is returned):

- `POST https://localhost:44301/api/Städte`

  ```
  ["Dresden", "Chemnitz"]
  ```
- `POST https://localhost:44301/api/St%C3%A4dte`

  ```
  ["Dresden", "Chemnitz"]
  ```

Using `PUT` leads to an equivalent result! Rename `ä` to `ae` will work but I don't like to!

Does anybody know why routing breaks if a body is expected from controller's action? What's the best fix to offer URIs with umlauts to the customer?

---

ASP.NET Core Web Server Log:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:44301/api/St��dte application/json 23
trce: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware[0]
      All hosts are allowed.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware[1]
      Request did not match any routes.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[9]
      Connection id "0HLGJ46FC5IM0" completed keep alive response.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 11.5071ms 404 
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[25]
      Connection id "0HLGJ46FC5IM0", Request id "0HLGJ46FC5IM0:00000002": started reading request body.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[26]
      Connection id "0HLGJ46FC5IM0", Request id "0HLGJ46FC5IM0:00000002": done reading request body.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[32]
      Connection id "0HLGJ46FC5IM0", Request id "0HLGJ46FC5IM0:00000002": the application completed without reading the entire request body.
```

---

UPDATE 27-06-2019:

ASP.NET Core 2.2:

- POST works now
- GET doesn't :-(

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/11640

Comment: Do not use special characters when you define your variables. It is the standard, follow the standards!

Comment: @Lewis86 Please tell me where the standard is written.

Comment: for c#: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions
for javacript: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp

Comment: @Lewis86 I guess you point to "DO NOT use ... nonalphanumeric characters." First I would consider 'ä' as an alphanumeric character. And even if not I'm not sure I can avoid it if 1) the customer wants to call https://localhost:44301/api/Städte and 2) the project teams refrain from term translation (respect to DDD).

Comment: You are having problems because of the use of special characters. But do the way you want to do. Good luck!

Comment: Are you sure, that you're using correct url + content/type, because I tried it locally, and it worked as expected.

Comment: @LukasKubis I tried it on a different machine: Server = Visual Studio 2017/IIS Express, Client = Postman: `POST https://localhost:44301/api/Städte ["Dresden", "Chemnitz"]` with the header `Content-Type:application/json` returns 404(NOT FOUND)

Comment: Try to use just http. I was having problems with https and postman locally

Comment: @LukasKubis No, 404 again.

Comment: I'm ok with not using special characters when possible but, I'm doing a GET request that receives a 'ñ' in the parameter value and the service returns 200 OK. The value of the parameter is out of our control and the action is not even reached. It should not be a 200 but, maybe, a 400. If I find how to solve it I'll post an answer to the question.

Comment: @Dodger I've tested it on .NET Core 2.2: POST works, GET doesn't :-( (https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/11640)

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you tried using string[] instead of IEnumarable. although it's the same,

Also, are you setting the content type to "application/json" in the header when doing a post?

eg. "Content-Type":"application/json"

Comment: No, using `string[]` instead of `IEnumerable<string>` doesn't work, either. Yes, Postman automatically adds `"Content-Type":"application/json"` to the request header.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why special character requests break only if a body is passed. **This is probably a bug!**

I'd like to describe a workaround. First what happens:

1. Client (e.g. Postman) sends UTF-8 "Städte".
2. The UTF-8 byte stream of "Städte" is send: `53 74 c3 a4 64 74 65` (UTF-8 "ä" needs 2 bytes: `c3 a4`!)
3. For some reasons ASP.MVC Core assume Codepage 8859-1 (Latin-1) and not UTF-8 in URI: so `53 74 c3 a4 64 74 65` becomes "StÃ¤dte". For requests with bodies only!

That's why I added `[Route("api/StÃ¤dte")]` to the controller which lets Postman get status 200(OK):

```
[Route("api/StÃ¤dte")] // UTF-8 "ä" (0xc3a4) → ISO-8859-1 "Ã¤".
[Route("API/STÃ„DTE")] // UTF-8 "Ä" (0xc384) → ISO-8859-1 "Ã„".

[Route("api/[controller]")] // Default.
[ApiController]
public class StädteController : ControllerBase
{
    //...
}
```

Note: URL encoded requests work always by default!!! So you don't need to add `[Route("api/St%C3%A4dte")]` or `[Route("API/ST%C3%84DTE")]`.

---

For further problems like that: Use [ISO-8859-1](https://www.charset.org/charsets/iso-8859-1) code page to compose your umlauts. Here's an extract:

```
UTF-8 → Binary → 8859-1
----------------------
ä       C3 A4    Ã¤
Ä       C3 84    Ã„
ö       C3 B6    Ã¶
Ö       C3 96    Ã–
ü       C3 BC    Ã¼
Ü       C3 9C    Ãœ
ß       C3 9F    ÃŸ
```